# DART fails in Chrome 44

Tags: google-chrome, dart

I installed the new Chrome 44 and my DART application stopped working (it worked in Chrome 43).
I see this in my developer console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.shadowRoot.getElementsByTagName is not a function
mypage.html:5884 Uncaught TypeError: this.shadowRoot.getElementsByTagName is not a function
mypage.html:6389 Uncaught TypeError: this.shadowRoot.getElementsByTagName is not a function
mypage.html:7770 Uncaught TypeError: this.shadowRoot.getElementsByTagName is not a function
mypage.html:11479 Uncaught TypeError: this.shadowRoot.getElementsByTagName is not a function
mypage.html:11918 Uncaught TypeError: this.shadowRoot.getElementsByTagName is not a function
mypage.html:12486 Uncaught TypeError: this.shadowRoot.getElementsByTagName is not a function
mypage.html:12811 Uncaught TypeError: this.shadowRoot.getElementsByTagName is not a function
mypage.html:13079 Uncaught TypeError: this.shadowRoot.getElementsByTagName is not a function
mypage.html:13697 Uncaught TypeError: this.shadowRoot.getElementsByTagName is not a function
```

My suspicion is that a bug that is introduced in the new Chrome release.

However, if someone has more information on this, please, advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this was deprecated a while ago and now finally removed https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/m/#!msg/blink-reviews/r25yAE9YBMY/lwCGKQMppfkJ